# Isn't every algebraic operad equipped with a trivial weight?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, operads

In Loday–Vallette "[Algebraic Operads](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-30362-3)" they state the following result (Theorem 6.6.2, Operadic twisting morphism fundamental theorem):

*Let $P$ be a connected weight graded differential oeprad and let $C$ be a connected weight graded differential cooperad. Let $\alpha: C \to P$ be an operadic twisting morphism [respecting the weights]. The following assertions are equivalent: [blah blah blah, does not depend on the weights].*

Isn't every operad (and cooperad) equipped with a trivial weight filtration (concentrating everything to weight $0$), and hence the assertions that follow are always equivalent? Note that none of the assertions that follow depend on the weight filtrations.

I'm a bit confused. I guess I'm missing some details. Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: I imagine "connected" mean that there is essentially nothing with weight zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment of Tom Goodwillie is correct. In the book, a *connected* weight graded operad is one that decomposes as:
$$\mathcal{P} = \mathbb{K} \mathrm{id} \oplus \mathcal{P}^{(1)} \oplus \mathcal{P}^{(2)} \oplus \dots,$$
where $\mathcal{P}^{(0)} = \mathbb{K} \mathrm{id}$. See Section 6.3.11, "Weight Grading."

This is a nontrivial condition. For example, if $\mathcal{P} = \mathcal{P}(1)$ is generated by a single unary operation $f$ satisfying $f \circ f = \mathrm{id}$, then it cannot be given a weight grading that makes it connected.